# AsyncStorage in react native expo- how to get data?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, asyncstorage

I'm making a fake toy buy app using react native and expo, I want to add certain details about the toy to the shopping cart page. I think I have set the data properly (I didn't know how to check), but I'm not able to get and show the stored data.

This is my component that sets up the format for any toy product page. This component is implemented into every toy page, so I used this page to set the data like so:

```
const SlugFormat = ({id, image, name, price, longDesc, seller, type}) => {
    
    // some functions and states

    const setData = async (id, name, price, quantity, image) => {
    try {
      const jsonValue = JSON.stringify(id, name, price, quantity, image)
      await AsyncStorage.setItem('ToyProduct', jsonValue)
    } catch(e) {

    }
    console.log('Done')
  }
    return (
      // code that sets up how the page is laid out
  )
}
```

And this is my cart page where I try to get the data, but nothing shows. It currently only shows 'getData' on the page, not any of the values.

```
const Cart = () => {
  const getData = async () => {
    return await AsyncStorage.getItem('ToyProduct');
  }
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>{getData.name}</Text>
    </View>
  )
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: getData is a function so when you are calling getData.name your getting the name of the function, getData is also an async function so you'll have to await it as you do with AsyncStorage.getItem. I'd suggest studying how async/await works and then try again

Comment: Take a look at the documentation: https://react-native-async-storage.github.io/async-storage/docs/usage. All needed info is there.

Answer (score 1):

The way your `stringify` your value is **incorrect**.

```
 const jsonValue = JSON.stringify(id, name, price, quantity, image)
```

Try wrapping it into an object like this:

```
const jsonValue = JSON.stringify({id, name, price, quantity, image})
```

Comment: return JSON.parse(await AsyncStorage.getItem('ToyProduct'));

You need add 'JSON.parse'